# List won't reverse

Tags: python, list

So i'm attempting to do the Eular project. If you don't know its 400 or so mini programming challenges. I just started and i'm on number 4. So the challenge is to find the largest number that can be reversed and equals itself and it has to be the product of two three digit numbers. For example 111*111=12321 if reversed it still equals 12321.
here is the code.

```
#Eular
x=999
y=999
z=[]
win=0
w=[]
while x>99:
    while y>99:
        z.append(x*y)
        w.append(z.reverse())
        if z==w:
            print(x,y)
            print("DONE")
            win=1
            winx=x
            winy=y
        z=[]
        y=y-1
        w=[]
    y=999
    x=x-1
print("done")
if win==1:
    print(winx,winy)
```

So whats happening is that the w list is not working. It says it can't reverse the z list. Please help its probably just a stupid mistake, but i can't figure it out.
Thanx

Comment: `z.reverse()` returns `None` because it reverses the list *in place*.

Comment: You are cheating!!! ;)

Comment: You're adding a number to `z` and then reversing the order of the elements in the list, not the digits of the first value in the list, so `reverse()` won't work, period (regardless of the issues others have pointed out).

Comment: `z.reverse()` modifies `z`, it does not return a reversed copy of the array `z`

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't think the sort of "reverse" mentioned in the alleged duplicate question has any relation to this, does it?  This seems like something completely different.

Comment: so how do you fix it?

Comment: @SouthpawHare: `w` should probably be a copy of `z`, reversed, so `w = z[::-1]` is what I *think* was intended. But the code, as posted, is suffering from many more problems.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm confused.  It looks like the duplicate question is for reversing the order of items in a list, while the question is about reversing the digits in a number, i.e. making a palindrome-detector for integers.

Comment: @SouthpawHare: I did say there are *many* things wrong in this question. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Perhaps so, but conceptually-speaking, I would think that the duplicate question doesn't answer the OP's original intent.

Comment: @SouthpawHare: The dupe at the very least tells you about several different techniques to produce a reversed sequence. Most of these apply to strings as well as lists. Note that this post failed to actually state a proper question; no error information was included. I just VTCed for the most obvious flaw in the code.

Comment: "It says it can't reverse the z list." No, it does not. The best way to understand error messages is to **read them**. The best way to communicate error messages to others is to **copy and paste them**, [completely](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/). The best way to understand wrong output is to **examine it** and **read the documentation**. The best way to communicate wrong output is to **show it**.